# Protect a web api from begin called by other apps

Tags: asp.net, api, security, oauth, asp.net-web-api

I am developing an asp.net web api app, and using OWIN and identity to implement oauth for my aplication security. For each  registered user, I also save a client id and hash as described [here](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/simple-oauth-server-implementing-a-simple-oauth-server-with-katana-oauth-authorization-server-components-part-1). But I dont want other developers be able to use my api and create their own app using the client id (and other credentials) they have.

Is it possible ?

Comment: it depends on your application design. is anyone can register and  have an account in your application ?

Comment: Actually I have an android app which use this api and users can register from android app.

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, you have to encrypt your network traffic between mobile device and API. Because attackers can obtain sensitive data (which is API Token in this case) via proxy . Also you need to do SSL Pinning because of you need to be sure about public key is yours, otherwise attackers manage to get sensitive data again with same method. ( Please check out : https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning )

You shouldn't authenticate users with username/password. I suggest to you use api key, therefor you can send user actions to server side like following patterns.

https://example.com/api/APIKEYOVERHERE/action

Als you can watch this talk about Secure Your API - Tips for REST + JSON Developers.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FeSdFhsKGG0